# Why is booktabs adding vertical space between rows of table?

Tags: tables, booktabs, excel2latex

I'm experimenting with the excel2latex tool to quickly get my Excel tables to latex code. However if I check the `use booktabs package` option in the Excel2Latex AddIn and paste my code into Latex I get some vertical space which is not filled by border or by background color.
If I disable the `booktabs option` it just works fine.

So my Question is: **How can I use the booktabs package with a complete background color fill and closed borders?**

See my MWE and Screenshots below or visit https://www.overleaf.com/11497648yfczshwxcwkc

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx, booktabs, multirow}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bigstrut}

\begin{document}

% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Tabelle1'
\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{|r|r|r|}
    \toprule
    1 & 2 & 23 \\
    \midrule
    12 & 2 & 2 \\
    \midrule
    13 & 1 & 1 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%


% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Tabelle1' without bookstabs
\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{|r|r|r|}
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 23 \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    12 & 2 & 2 \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    13 & 1 & 1 \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%


\end{document}
```

Table Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzgY3.jpg

Comment: This is by design in order to improve the look and readability of tables.

Comment: ok I understand that it adds some vertical space to improve the readability, but why are the vertical lines not growing to the same height? Is this by intention as well?

Comment: Well, using vertical lines in tables is not recommended, especially with `booktabs`

Comment: The manual says even more ``Never, ever use vertical rules''.

Comment: OK it's even in the first paragraph...shame on me ^^ but thanks anyways!